# Tried to load Angular more than once + included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whenever I press the "Get started" button on my [website](http://dingocv.herokuapp.com/), the screen goes black and I get the following errors in the console log. I do not see this issue locally, prior to `grunt build` being run and me deploying to Heroku:

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

The code for my index.html is as follows, full code [here](https://pastebin.com/4NJ5bK7C):

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBHuxIv-E8l4YRp_vWjW7X22gRNwI1xN30"></script>
  <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-modal-service/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/vsGoogleAutocomplete/dist/vs-google-autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/vsGoogleAutocomplete/dist/vs-autocomplete-validator.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

What else could be causing the issue?

### Update

I've included my Grunt task as well: https://pastebin.com/3JiaQwXU.

Comment: maybe, your grunt task are duplicate the  `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBHuxIv-E8l4YRp_vWjW7X22gRNwI1xN30"></script>`

Comment: Here is my grunt task: https://pastebin.com/3JiaQwXU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon analysing  your page in the dev console, it seems that you are indeed loading the script twice. I shall explain.

Follow the image below[image]

On clicking Get started you are basically loading the entire page again. Check html of `getstarted.html`. If you intend to use templates then the template should have only a portion of the view not the entire site from the very top.

Comment: You can verify this in the networks tab when you click on get started. The html loaded has the same content as the first html served from the sever.

Comment: Here is the code for getstarted.html, I do not load it in there: https://pastebin.com/YucNXgde

Comment: For some reason the getstarted.html is loading the entire content of the page

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here you go: https://pastebin.com/G4FnjFrJ. Note that it is dependent on https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service

Comment: I was reading the documents, the controller that one attaches to the modal is that specific to only the modal. I see in your code you have attached it to the main controller. Can you see what happens when you attach it to a modal controller. Check the docs.

Comment: I attach it to the main controller because I need to access bind it to `vm.contactData = {};`? Is my line of reasoning incorrect. Do you reckon that `getstarted.html` is loading the whole of the page for this reason?

Comment: I updated it to use angular-strap, but I am still getting the same issue: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/